# Confused by book's given solution to basic combinatorial problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This problem is an example in a textbook. I don't fully understand the result.

> In order to play a game of basketball, 10 children at a playground divide themselves into two teams of 5 each. How many different divisions are possible?

I answer it as follows: $$ {10 \choose 5}{5\choose5} = {10\choose5} $$

My logic for this solution is: you have ten players, choose 5 to form a team. (Note you have de facto created the second team, as the resulting 5 that were not chosen in any given combination comprise the competing team). For consistency, 5 players remain choose 5.

The answer the book gives is 126. I'm not sure what is wrong with my logic.

Comment: I can only confirm that your answer is correct, and 126 makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Big numbers like that make my head spin. Let's try it with smaller numbers, OK? Suppose there are $2$ children, to be divided into two teams of $1$ each. How many different divisions are possible? Is it $\binom21\binom11=2$? Or is it half that?

Comment: @bof Excellent question. Clearly it is half. But what part of my logic is incorrect? Where am I double counting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're treating the teams as labelled; the book is treating the teams as unlabelled, i.e. it doesn't matter whether you select a team or its complement, you still get the same two teams, so you need to divide by $2$.

Comment: So just to clarify, I am double counting by considering  team {1,2,3,4,5} and team {6,7,8,9,10} as unique results, when in fact they represent the same outcomes. Is that correct?

Comment: @d0rmLife: Yes -- well, these two sets obviously don't represent the same two teams, but choosing these two sets results in the same two teams being formed.

Comment: Yes, my language was a little sloppy. Just to ensure I understand, if we were to ask the same original question, with the caveat that a team may be labelled as "home" or "away", then the correct answer would be ${10\choose5}$ because similar (but differently ordered) results are in fact unique due to the home/away designation. In other words, we could say that the ${10\choose5}$ represents the home team. Is this right?

Comment: @d0rmLife: That's exactly right.

Comment: @d0rmLife  Another way to see this is to suppose Amanda is one of the ten players.  A choice of two teams is determined by which $4$ of the other $9$ players will be on her team.  There are $\binom{9}{4}$ such choices.